# Increase a variable in a loop and for each increment, apply for each new thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, mysql-backup

How to increase a variable every time I create a new `Thread` and store that value? I want to do mysqlbackup in each thread for different databases, and I will get the curBytes/totalBytes completed on Class1.cs. I want to update that value into `datagridview.Row[iterate].Cell[2]` ***simultaneously between threads*** where iterate corresponds with value 0 for first thread, 1 for second thread and so on.

I have tried using `Interlocked.Increment` and `lock()` but they seem not to work. I don't want to use `BackgroundWorker`.

This is the code that I haven't done anything to change `datagridIterate` (the value that iterate through datagridview Rows)

Form.cs:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    restoreUI();
}

public void restoreUI()
{
    mysqlUtils msu = new mysqlUtils(); 
    foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            msu.Restore(row.Cells[1].Value?.ToString(), server.Text, username.Text,
                pwd.Text, row.Cells[0].Value?.ToString());
        }
        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Class1.cs:

```
namespace Utils
{
    public class mysqlUtils
    {
        public int total;
        public int cur;

        public void Restore(string filename, string server, string user,
            string password, string db)
        {
            string constring = "server=" + server + ";user=" + user +
                ";pwd=" + password + ";database=" + db + ";";
            string file = "C:\\Users\\SQL FILES\\" + filename;
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                {
                    using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conn;
                        conn.Open();

                        mb.ImportInfo.IntervalForProgressReport = 50;

                        mb.ImportProgressChanged += updateProgress;
                        mb.ImportFromFile(file);

                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateProgress(object sender, ImportProgressArgs e)
    {
        total = (int)e.TotalBytes;
        cur = (int)e.CurrentBytes;
        Form4 form4 = (Form4)Application.OpenForms[0];
        form4.updateProgressValue(total, cur);
    }
}
```

How should I manage to change `datagridIterate` that will have value `i` for first thread, `i+1` for the next thread and so on? I would highly appreciate if you have any support.

Comment: Please consider posting an [mcve].

Comment: I'm going to assume that the call to `msu.Restore` is time consuming. But it appears it might be doing something with the data grid - however that's not allowed in the thread. We really need to see complete code.

Comment: the Restore function will restore mysql database . And I will get restore progess from that function and add percentage completed to datagrid

Comment: @DatCongDinh - Great. Can we please have a [mcve]? Your code is all over the place.

Comment: sorry about that i will edit it

Comment: I want to copy, paste, and compile your code and almost have it run. Then I can refactor and give you something that works.

Comment: I will edit it now, it will take several minutes

Comment: I have edited it please have a look. Basically my Mysql Database Restore program will show progress on each rows  of my datagridview and the percentage will be update  on Percentage column of each row at a same time

Comment: Im having trouble with updating value on different rows. My program can only update the first row since my row's coordinate is created with value 0 and doesnt change when another thread is created ( I expect to increase that value by 1 every time a new thread is created)

Comment: You can't access any UI element in a non-UI thread. All of the parameters `row.Cells[1].Value?.ToString(), server.Text, username.Text, pwd.Text, row.Cells[0].Value?.ToString()` cannot be accessed inside the thread.

Comment: @DatCongDinh - It's still not a [mcve]. I've had to add heaps of code to get it close to compiling, but now I'm getting the error `CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'iterate' of 'UserQuery.mysqlUtils.Restore(string, string, string, string, string, int)'`.

Comment: I had to add a `updateProgressValue` method to the form.

Comment: Calling `Form4 form4 = (Form4)Application.OpenForms[0];` in your `mysqlUtils` class is a bad design as it's creating a strong coupling from the DB to the UI. That's generally very bad.

Comment: It appears you have `t.Start` inside your `Thread` constructor. There are a lot of issues with your code before we can even start answering your question.

Comment: In my case it works. I have a form and when I filled all informations and press the Restore button (button1) . My program will loop through every rows of datagrid and for each row the restore progress will start. I've run many times and it works

Comment: how do i private message you so that I can give you my full code

Comment: oh please delete the last int in Restore, I've just deleted the iterate value because im not sure whether it's a good place to place the variable

Comment: i'm sorry , except for ```Form4 form4 = (Form4)Application.OpenForms[0];``` . The rest is my typo. Since there are other condition check code that I crossed out when posting to stackoverflow, and I didn't cross them out properly. I have just updated

Comment: Now, your question is asking about `datagridIterate`. There is no `datagridIterate` in your code.

Comment: I can't find the `datagridIterate` variable inside the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a big hint for your code that might help you to understand what you need.

Try this:

```
public class Form4 : Form
{
    private DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
    private TextBox server = new TextBox();
    private TextBox username = new TextBox();
    private TextBox pwd = new TextBox();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RestoreUI();
    }

    public void RestoreUI()
    {
        MySqlUtils msu = new MySqlUtils();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string filename = row.Cells[1].Value?.ToString();
            string s = server.Text;
            string user = username.Text;
            string password = pwd.Text;
            string db = row.Cells[0].Value?.ToString();
            Thread t = new Thread(() => msu.Restore(filename, s, user, password, db, UpdateProgress));
            t.Start();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateProgress(object sender, ImportProgressArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            /* add your code here to update the UI */
        }));
    }
}
```

And your `MySqlUtils` class.

```
public class MySqlUtils
{
    public void Restore(string filename, string server, string user, string password, string db, ImportProgressChange updateProgress)
    {
        string constring = "server=" + server + ";user=" + user + ";pwd=" + password + ";database=" + db + ";";
        string file = "C:\\Users\\SQL FILES\\" + filename;
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    conn.Open();

                    mb.ImportInfo.IntervalForProgressReport = 50;

                    mb.ImportProgressChanged += updateProgress;
                    mb.ImportFromFile(file);

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NB: I've changed the naming conventions to standard C#.

Comment: hello sir, I was supposed to reply you early but I planned to answer you when I have the final answer to my problem, and I still haven't find the answer to it

Comment: Is there any way to add more Variable in UpdateProgress. For example: ```public void UpdateProgress(object sender, ImportProgressArgs e, *int datagridIterate*)``` and how do I handle it in my Restore() function

Comment: the purpose of ```datagridIterate``` variable is  to hold my Datagridview iteration in the ```foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)```,

Comment: ```public void UpdateProgressValue(object sender, ImportProgressArgs e,int datagridIterate)
{
this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                double percent = ((double)e.CurrentBytes / (double)e.TotalBytes) * 100;
                string sPercent = percent.ToString("n2");
                curPercent = sPercent + "%";
                if (datagridIterate == dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
                    return;
                    this.dataGridView1.Rows[datagridIterate].Cells[2].Value = curPercent;
                }));         
        }
```

Comment: Initially, instead of adding ```int datagridIterate``` into ```UpdateProgressValue``` , I created a public int inside Class1 and it will be updated everytime a Thread activates ```Restore(///,int iterate){ datagridIterate=iterate;}``` but that public int will be updated cross thread when a new Thread activates the code, so instead of having a specific value for a thread, it will be changed cross thread and my datagridview updates value at the last Row

Comment: The second comment is my main question, the 5th comment is my failed attempt with other different way